# Is "gilded" usually associated with gold as an element or as a colour?

Tags: meaning

I know that *gilded* [means](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/gilded)

> covered or highlighted with gold or something of a golden color

So it can be associated both with gold as a chemical element or just the colour.

Some situations might give away which of these interpretations is the correct one (e.g. a gilded car is hardly covered in gold), but what about ambiguous ones (e.g. gilded earrings)?

**When you read *gilded* in a sentence without further specifications, do you think about an item covered in real gold or just painted in such colour?**

I'm looking for a "standard" interpretation (if there is one) on the matter, but also personal opinions, if properly supported, are accepted.

Comment: I doubt you'd often see "gilded car" - I certainly can't imagine anyone saying that to describe the colour. You wouldn't normally see "gilded earrings" either. They'd be "gilt earrings" if they had a *gold-coloured* plating, and if they were actually plated with gold they'd normally be described as *gold-plated*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: isn't [gilt](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/gilt) the same as _gilded_? I know that you could just describe things with different terms (e.g. gold painted car), but that doesn't answer my question.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: As I stated in my question, I wasn't sure such interpretation existed or not. I'll be glad if you'd decide to make an answer out of your comments as they seem sensible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gilt and gilded mean the same, but they're not always used interchangeably. For instance, with earrings, "gilt" is [far more common](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=gilt%20earrings,gilded%20earrings&year_start=1860&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) than "gilded". But "gilded cage" is [far more common](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=gilt%20cage,gilded%20cage&year_start=1860&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) than "gilt cage".

Personally I'd say on balance "gilded" is more dated. "Gilt" is slightly more likely to be used of real gold - or high-value, as opposed to highly-decorative (as in [gilt-edged securities](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/g/gilt-edged-securities.asp#axzz1YE6dS7E3)).

More often, "gold-plated" is used for the real thing. I can't quantify *gold-plated connectors* in Google Books because of the hyphen, but quotated as a Google web-search it gets over 8,000,000 hits as opposed to less than 2000 for *gilded connectors* and less than 200 for *gilt connectors*.

OP is looking for a distinction in *meaning* that doesn't in fact exist. It's just that there are many idiomatic *usages* where one word is used much more than the other.

Answer (score 1):

Most of time I see the word, it is being used metaphorically ("Gilded Age", "gilding a lily") and the implication is usually that there is some level of fakery or at least shallowness. So for those cases, at least, I would say the interpretation is "painted" or at least "covered in a very thin layer of not quite pure gold, and even then only covered on the surfaces that face outward".

Answer (score 0):

M-W says:

> 1: to overlay with or as if with a thin covering of gold
>
> 2 a : to give money to
>   b : to give an attractive but often deceptive appearance to
>   c archaic : to make bloody
>   — gild·er noun
>   — gild the lily : to add unnecessary ornamentation to something beautiful in its
>   own right

I often use the expression *A gilded cage* about a company with so many perks that it is impossible to find a "better" job.

If you use the word gilded about some metal, I would personally expect it to have a covering of real gold.

Comment: I think given MW specifically say the *"smear with blood"* meaning is archaic, they should certainly do the same for *"to give money to"*. I'd be surprised if it's been used with that meaning in print more than a couple of times in the past century - the most recent I can find is [this one from 1914](http://books.google.com/books?id=2ZHSAAAAMAAJ&q=%22gild+him%22&dq=%22gild+him%22&hl=en&ei=kgB2TtPeDvK20QWkoKWXCA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=6&ved=0CEcQ6AEwBTgK), which is refering to much earlier times anyway.